# Msi Silent Installation:capture the context parameter after commit and set these values in file

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I have an installer named App-Test.msi.I have an associated Installer class named "Helper"
Here i have done few override to create application pool,Read the Context paramters.
The context paramter i read is given as part of Custom action as below:

SERVER="[SERVER]"
TARGETDIR="[TARGET]"

Here SERVER is a value picked from UserInterface part of Installer.

This works perfectly via GUI based Installer Interface.

Now,I want this to run msi installer silently picking up the value for TARGETDIR and SERVER through command line as below.I used ORCA tool to add additional property SERVER and configured value to "[SERVER]" as well actual server name.But somehow the value for these are not set .Hence the context parameter also returning empty value.

msiexec /I App-Test.msi /qn  TARGETDIR=D:\Websites\Default\ SERVER=DUMMYSERVER

Can anyone suggest a better approach or point where i have gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have added a "Textboxes (A)" Dialog to the User Interface of your Installer.  The Textboxes Dialog will have several "Edit" Controls such as: {Edit1, Edit2, Edit3, Edit4}.  Presumably the "Edit1Property" for your Dialog is "SERVER".  The "Edit1Value" will need to be: [SERVER] in order for the property values passed in from the command line to pass-through.  As it stands, it is likely that the default values for those "Edit" controls are actually overriding the property values that are passed in from the command prompt.  The effects of this change will cause the Default values to no longer appear in your standard installation; instead, the textboxes will be blank.  I am sure with some additional work in the Custom Action that this could be taken care of, but I haven't yet figured that part out.

[image]

Also, properties that return a directory must be surrounded by double quotes and require a trailing backslash:

Example:

TARGETDIR="[TARGETDIR]\"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz(v=vs.80).aspx